# Update diffrent controller when POST is successful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two controllers visible in separate views at the same time.

I need to update view A from view B

**For example**

When I send POST while viewing get-by-id page and when I watch view A ( list of items ) I want the update of that single post. Can I force the controller to get the information again and update the scope or.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $broadcast to communicate between sibling scopes.

If you have a master scope and two children scopes (one for view A and one for view B), you can do a broadcast from the master scope to inform the children that something happenned, and then in scope A you listen to that particular broadcast.

Example :

Master scope
 |- Scope A
 |- Scope B

in the B controller, when your envent occurs, you can use :

> $parent.$broadcast("event")

This will emit a broadcast from the master scope which can be intercepted in the A controller :

> $scope.$on("event", function())

In there your function() will be the one which updates your A scope.

[Angular doc for broadcast](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast)

Answer (score 1):

I would use events. When the POST is successfull send an event from controller B

`$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', data)`

and add a listener on controller A

`$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event){ 
// update view A
}`

Answer (score 1):

Within the POST callback from A send an event with the updated list, like this:

```
$scope.$emit('listUpdateEvent',$scope.list);
```

Within the controller of B have this to listen to the update of this:

```
$rootScope.$on('listUpdateEvent',function(e,_list) {
    $scope.list = _list;
});
```